# Airflow - Exception while trying to heartbeat! Sleeping for 5.0 seconds

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow DAG that has nearly 50 tasks running in parallel. Occasionally, I get this exception.  "Exception while trying to heartbeat! Sleeping for 5.0 seconds". The Airflow documentation says that its due to the failure of a periodic heartbeat from tasks and the scheduler considered them as zombies. Any fix would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making connections to DB or using many ports then try to close the connections and free the ports. That might work.